# Submitting highscore in PHP

Tags: php, game, session

So, I am interested, what is the proper way to submit a highsocre (such as of a Pacman game) in PHP? [Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/svg-pacman/code/ci/master/tree/setPacmanHighscore.php) is what I tried:

```php
<?php
if (array_key_exists("HTTP_USER_AGENT", $_SERVER)) {
    $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
} else {
    $browser = "none";
}
if (substr($browser, 0, strlen("Opera")) !== "Opera" &&
        substr($browser, 0, strlen("Mozilla/5.0")) !== "Mozilla/5.0") {
    exit("Please access this URL with a proper browser! As far as I know, no browser in which you can actually play that PacMan has User Agent that does not start either with \"Opera\" or with \"Mozilla/5.0\".\n");
}
if (!array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER) || $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != "https://svg-pacman.sourceforge.io/") {
    exit("Your browser did not set the HTTP referer header to the URL of the PacMan game, so we cannot save your highscore. Sorry about that!\n");
}
session_start();
if (!array_key_exists('first_random_number', $_SESSION) || !array_key_exists('second_random_number', $_SESSION) || !array_key_exists('sumOfRandomNumbers', $_GET) || $_GET['sumOfRandomNumbers'] != $_SESSION['first_random_number'] + $_SESSION['second_random_number']) {
    session_destroy();
    exit("The session does not seem to be properly set! It can be both a server error or a misconfiguration of your browser. " .
            (
            (array_key_exists('first_random_number', $_SESSION) && array_key_exists('second_random_number', $_SESSION) && array_key_exists('sumOfRandomNumbers', $_GET)) ?
                    "The random numbers sent to JavaScript in \"<code>pacman.php</code>\" were"
                    . $_SESSION['first_random_number'] . " and "
                    . $_SESSION['second_random_number'] .
                    ", and your browser claims the sum of them is " . $_GET['sumOfRandomNumbers'] . ". " :
                    "") .
            "Unfortunately, we cannot set the new highscore!");
}
session_destroy();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Saving the highscore for PacMan in JavaScript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Attempting to save a highscore...<br>
<?php
$player = $_GET['player'];
if (strpos($player, " ") !== FALSE || strpos($player, "<") !== FALSE || strpos($player, ">") !== FALSE || strpos($player, "&") !== FALSE || strlen($player) == 0 || strlen($player) > 12)
    $player = "anonymous";
$score = intval($_GET['score']);
$datoteka = fopen("pachigh.txt", "r");
$current_highscore = intval(fgets($datoteka));
fclose($datoteka);
if ($score <= $current_highscore) {
    ?>Sorry about that, but higher highscore has already been submitted!<?php
        } else {
            $hash1 = $_GET['hash'];
            if (is_numeric($score) && $score < 100000) {
                $hash = 7;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $score / 127; $i++) {
                    $hash += $i;
                    $hash %= 907;
                }
                if ($hash - $hash1) {
                    ?>Invalid hash!<?php
                } else {
                    $datoteka = fopen("pachigh.txt", "w");
                    if ($datoteka === FALSE) {
                        ?>Server error: cannot open the &quot;<code>pachigh.txt</code>&quot; file for writing!<?php
                    } else {
                        fprintf($datoteka, "%d\n%s\n", $score, $player);
                        fclose($datoteka);
                        ?>
                        Successfully saved the new highscore!
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            window.close();
                        </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    } else {
        ?>
                Server error!
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The statement "_Here is what I tried:_" leads me to ask - does it work to the best of your knowledge? And what exactly do you mean by "_proper_"?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Yes, it works to the best of my knowledge. But I do not know if it is possible to cheat it, or even make cross-site-scripting attacks.

Comment: your question is poorly posed; The review that you should request is about whether your code has an inconspicuous security problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example may help you with writing more readable code, add addresses vulnerability CWE-209 by returning HTTP status codes instead of detailed error messages. From a security perspective the browser/referrer checks, 'hash' and random numbers you have implemented would not be effective at preventing abuse, though they may help to reduce it by adding some complexity. The simplest effective way to prevent abuse would be some kind of server-side element to the game where scores are only submitted after the user authenticates, or following some kind of successful time-based nonce challenge/response.

I recommend you separate your program logic from the user interface wherever possible - for example, try and use your PHP script like an API, returning response codes or JSON formatted data. Keep your HTML/CSS/Javascript separate from your PHP and use a javascript AJAX request to post the score to your API script, process the response and return an appropriate message to the user.

```
<?php

class PacmanScore {
    private $aParams = array();

    public function __construct() {
        if (!$this->CheckBrowser() || !$this->CheckReferer() || !$this->CheckRandomNos()) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
            exit;
        }
        if (!$this->CheckParameters()) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function HighScore() {
        if ($this->aParams['score'] <= $this->GetCurrentHighScore())
            return false;

        $this->SetNewHighScore();
        return true;
    }

    private function CheckBrowser() {
        $sUAgent = array_key_exists('HTTP_USER_AGENT', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';
        if (strlen($sUAgent) == 0)
            return true;

        if (strlen($sUAgent) >= 11)
            if (substr($sUAgent, 0, 11) == 'Mozilla/5.0')
                return true;

        if (strlen($sUAgent) >= 5)
            if (substr($sUAgent, 0, 5) == 'Opera')
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    private function CheckReferer() {
        $sReferer = array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
        return ($sReferer === 'https://svg-pacman.sourceforge.io/');
    }

    private function CheckRandomNos() {
        session_start();
        $iRandom1 = array_key_exists('first_random_number', $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION['first_random_number'] : 0;
        $iRandom2 = array_key_exists('second_random_number', $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION['second_random_number'] : 0;
        $iSum = array_key_exists('sumOfRandomNumbers', $_SESSION) ? $_SESSION['sumOfRandomNumbers'] : 0;
        session_destroy();
        if ($iSum == 0)
            return false;
        return ($iRandom1 + $iRandom2 == $iSum);
    }

    private function CheckParameters() {
        $this->aParams = array(
            'player' => isset($_GET['player']) ? $_GET['player'] : '',
            'score' => isset($_GET['score']) ? (int)$_GET['score'] : 0,
            'hash' => isset($_GET['hash']) ? (int)$_GET['hash'] : 0
        );

        /* Only allow letters and numbers in the player name */
        $this->aParams['player'] = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $this->aParams['player'];

        /* Trim player name to maximum 12 characters in length */
        $this->aParams['player'] = substr($this->aParams['player'], 0, 12);

        /* Minimum player name length of 3 characters */
        if (strlen($this->aParams['player']) < 3)
            return false;

        /* High score cannot be zero or above 99999 */
        if (($this->aParams['score'] == 0) || ($this->aParams['score'] > 99999))
            return false;

        /* Check supplied hash is correct */
        $iCheckHash = 7;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->aParams['score'] / 127; $i++) {
            $iCheckHash += $i;
            $iCheckHash %= 907;
        }
        if ($iCheckHash - $this->aParams['hash'])
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    private function GetCurrentHighScore() {
        $hScoresFile = fopen('pachigh.txt', 'r');
        if ($hScoresFile === false) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            exit;
        }
        $iHighScore = intval(fgets($hScoresFile));
        fclose($hScoresFile);
        return $iHighScore;
    }

    private function SetNewHighScore() {
        $hScoresFile = fopen('pachigh.txt', 'w');
        if ($hScoresFile === false) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            exit;
        }
        fprintf($hScoresFile, "%d\n%s\n", $this->aParams['score'], $this->aParams['player']);
        fclose($hScoresFile);
    }

}

$oPacmanScore = new PacManScore();
if ($oPacmanScore->HighScore()) {
    echo('Successfully saved the high score!');
} else {
    echo('Sorry about that, but higher highscore has already been submitted!');
}
```